# Populate multiple references (subdocuments) AND select SPECIFIC fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Using Mongodb, mongoose, nodejs, express....

I have a structure like this...

```
const EventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  eventDate: {
    type: Date
  },
  attendees: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Person'
    }
  ],
  staff: [
    {
      person: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
      },
      department: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['photography', 'data-entry', 'mgmt', 'other']
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

I know how to populate('attendees department'). That works fine and returns ALL data for both. But, because I'm dealing essentially with multiple populates, how do I SELECT the SPECIFIC fields that should be retrieved for attendees and department?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: populate('attendees department')

Comment: Dear, please don't  post your code in comment section. Show whole code and mention which fields you want.

Comment: @WebDevGuy2 this might be helpful: [How to select specific field in nested populate in mogoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37562129/how-to-select-specific-field-in-nested-populate-in-mogoose)

Comment: @MianMuhammad thanks but I'm trying to select specific fields in MULTIPLE populates

Comment: @WebDevGuy2 ok, would like to show what you have done so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your query as following, to populate multiple values & return only specific fields that you require

```
Event.find().populate([{
    path: 'attendees',
    model: 'Person',
    select: '_id name profile_pic' //Fields you want to return in this populate
}, {
    path: 'staff.person',
    model: 'User',
    select: '_id name profile_pic' //Fields you want to return in this populate
}])
```